# complex combination of a bernoulli random variable

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I would like to know what is the characteristic function of the follow complex combination of a Bernoulli random variable. Consider $$d= \Bigg\{\begin{array}{lcl}
        0 & \text{with probability} & 1-p\\
        1 & \text{with probability} & p\\
      \end{array} $$
a Bernoulli random variable and let $ z \in \mathbb{C}$, what is the characteristic function $\phi_{zd}(t)$? Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complex valued random variable $X$ the characteristic function $\phi_X$ is defined as the mapping $$\mathbb C \ni t \mapsto \phi_X(t) := E[\exp(i\;\text{Re} (\bar{t}X))] \in \mathbb C.$$ For a reference, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Generalizations) for instance.

Now, in our case $$\begin{align}\phi_{zd}(t)=E[\exp(i\;\text{Re}(\bar{t}zd))]&=p\;\exp(i\;\text{Re}(\bar{t}z)) + (1-p)\;\exp(i\;\text{Re}(\bar{t} \cdot 0))\\&= p\;\exp(i\;\text{Re}(\bar{t}z)) + (1-p).\end{align}$$

*Edit:* You're absolutely right! I missed the second summand.

If you identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R ^2$ via $$\mathbb C \ni z \leftrightarrow (z_1,z_2) := (\text{Re}(z),\text{Im}(z)) \in \mathbb R^2$$ then $$\text{Re} (\bar{t}z)=t_1z_1+t_2z_2= \;<t,z>$$ with $<\cdot,\cdot>$ being the standard scalar product in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but according to the reference the characteristic function is $p\exp(i\;\text{Re}(\bar{t}z)) + (1-p)?.$

Comment: @SamuelEduardoPinillaSanchez :

Comment: @SamuelEduardoPinillaSanchez  To your first question: No, that doesn't work, but you may use $exp(i\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$ for real $\alpha$. To your second question: You are right. The characteristic function factors for independent complex random variables. This might be seen as a consequence of bilinearity of the scalar product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ mentioned earlier. Complex valued random variables can be thought of very much like $\mathbb R^2$-valued random variables with the identification described above.

Comment: I understand, thanks for everything!.